# Avoid GitHub action buffering

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a Github repo that contains some Linux utilites.

To run test I use GitHub actions and some simple custom workflow that runs on a remote Linux server using self-hosted runner:

```yaml
name: CMake
on: [push]
env:  
  BUILD_TYPE: Release
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Build
      working-directory: ${{runner.workspace}}/Utils
      shell: bash
      run: cmake --build . --config $BUILD_TYPE

    - name: Run test
      working-directory: ${{runner.workspace}}/Utils
      shell: bash
      run: ./testing/test.sh
```

The workflow is very simple - I compile the source using `cmake` and then run a script from the same repo to test the build. The test script is a bash script and looks as following:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/bin

cd /path/to/bin

echo -e "Starting the tests"

./run_server &
./run_tests

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "successful"
else
    echo "failed"
    exit 1
fi
```

Here the scripts starts up an compiled application from my code (run_server) and then run the testing utility that communicates with it and prints a result.

Actually I use C `printf()` inside `run_tests` to print the output strings. If I run that on a local machine I get output like the following:

```bash
Starting the tests
test1 executed Ok
test2 executed Ok
test3 executed Ok
successful
```

Each test takes about 1 sec. so I the application prints a line like `testX executed Ok` one per second.

But if it runs using Github actions the output looks a bit different (copied from the Github actions console):

```bash
./testing/test.sh
  shell: /bin/bash --noprofile --norc -e -o pipefail {0}
  env:
    BUILD_TYPE: Release
    
Starting the tests   
successful
```

And even in this case the output from the bash script printed out only after the script has finished.
So I have 2 problems:

- no `printf()` output from the test application
- the script output (printed using `echo`) come only after the script has finished

I expected the same behavior from the Github action as I get on a local machine i.e. I see a lines printed ~ 1/sec. immediately.

It looks like Github action buffers all the output until a step executed and ignores all the print from the application that run inside the bash script.

Is there a way to get all the output in real time while a step executes?